# Meteor iterating through data & helpers

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, spacebars

I'm trying to iterate through the data but I want different layouts for different members in the team, like the President of the organisation should have col-md-12 (bootstrap - the entire width of the screen) but as there are 4 Vice Presidents they should have col-md-3 (width div by 4). Branch A employees could be col-md-3, B col-md-6 depending on what looks best.

This is what things look like right now. Commented parts are what I tried to do and didn't work.

In member_list.html

```
{{#each members}}
        {{> memberItem}}
{{/each}}
```

In member_list.js

```
    var CouncilMembers = [
    {
        name: "ABC",
        position: "President",
    },
    ---4 for VPs----
    ---several employees of different branches A, B, C----
    ]

Template.membersList.helpers({
    members: CouncilMembers
});
```

In member_item.html

```
<template name="memberItem">
    <div class="member">
    <!--{{#if Prez}}
        <div class="member-content">
            <h5 class="name">{{name}}</h5>
            <span class="department">{{position}}</span><br />

        </div>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if VicePrez}}
        <div class="member-content col-sm-3">
            <h5 class="name">{{name}}</h5>
            <span class="department">{{position}}</span><br />
        </div>
    {{/if}}-->
        <div class="member-content col-sm-4">
            <h5 class="name">{{name}}</h5>
            <span class="department">{{position}}/span><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In member_item.js

```
Template.memberItem.helpers({
 member: function() {
    return member;
 },
 /*
 Prez: function() {
    return member.find({position:'General Secretary'});
 },
 VicePrez: function() {
    return member.find({position:'Vice President'});
 }
 */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things to be done here:

- In `member_list.js` you are using an array. I expect that you use a Mongo Collection instead of that array, but that format is okay. So it will be something like:

```js
Template.membersList.helpers({
  members: () => CouncilMembers.find(),
});
```

- Then, in `member_item.js`, you will have in the scope all the information of the current item. So your helpers will be something like:

```js
Template.memberItem.helpers({
  Prez: function() {
    return this.position === 'General Secretary';
  },
  VicePrez: function() {
    return this.position === 'Vice President';
  }
});
```

After you implement something like that, your idea should work

Comment: Thanks this.position is what I needed. I plan to use a mongo collection and use subscribe, publish later.